# Get constructor of the type passed by template's formal argument

Tags: generics, typescript

I would like to pass a constructor of the type passed as a formal generic argument. When I try following

```
class Test {}

function g(x: new() => any): void {
    var y = new x();
}

function f<T>() {
    g(T);
}

f<Test>();
```

I get a compiler error (unknown name: T) and this JS:

```
function f() {
    g(T);
}
```

Looks like the generics in TS are used only to instruct typechecker, i.e. they are [phantom types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type). I need this to make a change to [Netjs](https://github.com/praeclarum/Netjs) code generator, so the change must be local to the function `f`. How do I get type's constructor from the generic parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Type-arguments as code in TypeScript (like you can in C#) because they are erased from the JS (as you already noticed). Just pass it in as a normal argument.

You can see the error reported by typescript as well.

[image: you saw the error]

Comment: The bad part is that this code is translated almost 1-to-1 from C#, and there's no way to pass it like that.